# WP7 - Get list of apps after synchronizing with pc

Tags: windows-phone-7

is there possibility to retrieve installed applications list on WP7 after my phone is connected to pc? (pc application, via zune etc...)

Thanks

Comment: This is more a superuser.com question as it's not programming related.

Answer (score 1):

What you CAN do is see a list of apps that you have purchased (including free apps that you have installed).  Click Settings|Account|Purchase History|Apps.

You can also go to my.windowsphone.com and click on Account, and see your app purchase history.  From the web site, you can also reinstall apps that you've uninstalled, remotely, without the phone even being hooked to the computer.  You can also click Marketplace, browse or search apps, and purchase/install them remotely, as well.  No connection to the PC needed.

What you can NOT do is see a list of what is currently installed on the phone.

Comment: My Zune software doesn´t seem to have account tab. Is this no longer supported or..... And also, I couldn´t find any API for zune software so making any plugins to retrieve informations I need is impossible. Or am I wrong? THanks

Comment: The latest version of Zune is 4.8 (Settings, Software, General, About Zune).  The last couple versions of Zune have had an Account under Settings.  Are you running the latest version?